# MySQL - Pruning Hash Partition

Tags: mysql, sql, hash, partition

Running MySQL 5.6. 
I have a hash-partitioned table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`branch_id` int(5) NOT NULL
...
...
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
PARTITION BY HASH( branch_id )
PARTITIONS 10;
```

From my understanding from the documentation, the hash partition performs a modulus operation on the key and partitions as follows: mod(key,*nm*) where *nm* is the number of partitions.

However, when I try a simple select no pruning occurs. The explain plan does not mention any partitions. Example query:

```
select count(*)
from transactions
where mod(branch_id,10)=1
```

How else can I prune the partitions?

Comment: MySQL's query optimiser isn't smart enough to recognise that `MOD(branch_id,10)` maps directly onto a single partition.  A query for `branch_id = 30` or `branch_id IN (30,40,50)` would however be pruned to only scan a single partition.

Comment: I would like to run a procedure on the table by its partitions. As in, proc_name(partition_number). Is there no way I can do this unless I create an additional column which consists of the mod(branch_id,10) value?

Comment: Well, you could create a temp table that contains only those `branch_id` values that are a certain value modulo 10 and then join against that... but (depending on your requirements) perhaps a `RANGE` partition would suit better here?  Then you can prune with `WHERE branch_id BETWEEN x AND y`.

Comment: @eggyal I thought of the "temp table" solution. The problem with the RANGE partition is that I don't have a reasonable way of dividing the range up; the branch_id is not distributed evenly since branches have been closed, opened, etc.

Comment: How did you even create partition on 'branch_id'? Curious..